# GE dishwasher sound proofing material

Tags: insulation, appliances, dishwasher, sound-proofing

Got a brand new GE dishwasher and its soundproofing wrap is quite thin, you can literally .. see through it (the photo doesn’t capture that) . The material measures around 1-2mm thick. Is this some sort of joke? I don’t think it has any sound proofing function being so slim. Is there some other use of this warp or is it safe to throw it away?

My previous dishwasher was Bosch and it had wrapping material that was maybe half an inch thick and I understand it helps with sound proofing and probably insulating too.

[image: material]

Comment: What **benefit** do you anticipate from removing it and  throwing it away? This seems like a pointless alteration to the brand-new machine.

Comment: @Ecnerwal It's not attached/glued to the machine at all. I don't have a lot of clearance, so because it's so slim I would expect it would just get jammed between countertop or sides and the dishwasher. GE can do better! Vs putting something subpar, why not leave it? Having that doesn't make any sense, as there is no utility. So I'd like to keep things simple

Comment: It probably produces higher frequency noise than your old dishwasher. Moving less water, they probably make more of a whine than a whoosh, so with a given μ of insulation (ballpark 1"=720Hz), an acoustic low-pass filter can be made with exponentially decreasing thickness as avg sound frequency increases. They could also use better materials than older models. I'm sure they did acceptance testing, but then again, they probably want to position quieter models with higher MSRPs, so the relative thinness isn't necessarily a matter of "chincing out", but of over-all economics and marketing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty flimsy. The appliance part stores show a replacement for it that looks pretty much the same as what you've got. Maybe they decided the machine just doesn't need heavy insulation It's safe to just throw the insulation away.

Comment: If his clearance is so minimal that the thin insulation will jam up upon insertion into the appliance cavity i don't think anything thicker will work better.

Comment: @RetiredATC  I answered this before the OP commented on not having a lot of clearance.

Answer (score 2):

It does more than you think. If you put some thought into it you'll realize that the sound it's intended to dampen travels laterally though it--out the gaps in your cabinetry--and not just through the thin dimension.